# How much is the admob wire transfer fee?

Tags: android, admob

I am a publisher on admob and I selected wire transfer as payment option.
Does anyone know how much are the transferring fees ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they do not cost anything, they are covered by AdMob but there maybe other charges that AdMob do not cover that are outside of AdMob (e.g. bank may charge a fee for converting dollars to your local currency)

[Here](http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1307283) is more information on the topic

About payment with AdMob

> AdMob will cover the fees required to send an ACH or wire transfer.
>   However, there may be additional fees charged to you for receiving an
>   ACH deposit or wire transfer that are outside of our control.
>
> Please also be aware that publisher payments are sent in U.S. Dollars,
>   your bank may charge a fee for converting this to your local currency.
>   We strongly encourage all publishers who elect to receive payments via
>   ACH deposit or wire transfer to contact their local bank to understand
>   the costs involved of receiving this type of payment.